# How to select a specific range in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select a `Range()` of column H, from H10 to all the way to bottom of H (unbounded). I tried `Range("H10:H")` but it doesn't work. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Range("H10:H" & Rows.Count)
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("name").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```